# Windows 7 password recovery

Tags: windows, hash

A few weeks ago I've changed the password on my old laptop, I forgot the password as I wasn't using it often. Now I need to recover the password because I used it to encrypt some important documents. I've extracted the hashes of the laptop using Ubuntu, I wanted to crack them with hashcat but I'm not sure what type of hashes they are, there are two hashes for each user. I've read that windows 7 uses NTLM v2 but there's 2 hashes, so I got confused.

> Administrator:500:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:c68bbf270f17d29960c0681c8202c07c:::

So could anybody tell me what type of hashes they are and how to crack them ?
the laptop runs windows 7 professional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try John the Ripper. Alternatively if you are willing to pay cash money there is a service which will do this for you for a fee:

- http://www.rixler.com/windows_service.htm

Only do this if it is your password or at the request of the owner. Remember that logging on to a computer without proper authority is a crime in most jurisdictions.